# How to inspect a COM object in the debugger's Locals window?

Tags: c#, debugging, com

I am developing an application that automates some stuff through the application's COM interface and I'd like to inspect the object in the Locals window, but the objects show only as `System.__ComObject` and when I expand them, nothing shows. I am not using the `dynamic` type but their actual types as exposed per the interop reference.

Thanks.

[image: ss]